# PHP else if methods isn't working?

Tags: php, if-statement

Hello I am trying to implement after they pay it checks how much they paid and inputs different variables in sql database with if methods.

**The problem:**
The problem is all the if methods return to this first option(inserts paid=1, and 30days) not sure what the problem is, is my if method broken?what's wrong please explain! thanks!

```
if(number_format($amount, 2) == 8.00) 
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli(******);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='1', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
} elseif (number_format($amount, 2) == 10.00) 
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli(******);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='2', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
} elseif (number_format($amount, 2) == 100.00) 
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli(******);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid='2', reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**Edit**: I tried with `$amount` and also tried using the names of the array from dropdown menu I have

```
array("Basic Package-Monthly", "8.00", "Month", "1", "0", "0"),
array("Premium Package-Monthly", "10.00", "Month", "1", "0", "0"),
array("Premium Package-Annually", "100.00", "Year", "1", "0", "0"),
```

Comment: You only need the `$mysqli = new mysqli(******);` once, above the `if` statement.

Comment: oh okay thanks robert, do u have any idea to fix the problem tho?

Comment: Same with `number_format($amount, 2)`.  If you put the result of that in a variable, you can just reference that variable in your `if` statements.  It has the added bonus of putting the numeric value in one place so that you can check it.

Comment: try to echo out / console log  the $amount value before if condition to check what actual value is

Comment: ya I did, I set the variable as $amount but still didn't work so wanted to try that code out just to see because I have no idea what the problem could be

Comment: You need to clean up the code first, then we can figure out what is wrong with it (assuming the problem doesn't resolve itself naturally when you clean up the code).

Comment: Give an example value for $amount

Comment: $amount gets it from array that I posted the array is this //service name   |   price  to charge   | Billing period  "Day", "Week", "Month", "Year"   |  how many periods of previous field per billing period | trial period in days | Trial amount the price to charge is the $amount

Comment: Can you make the suggested changes, and test your code again?  Edit the question with your new code.

Comment: alright one minute doing all the changes

Comment: The only reason your first if statement is firing would be because `number_format($amount,2)==8.00` is true which means `$amount` contains 8 or 8.00000000 or something that equates to 8.00 when formatted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why worry about the conditional statement, let the switch handle it. Leverage your `prepared` statement fully.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('******');
$paid = false;
$recurring = false;

switch(number_format($amount, 2)):
    case '8.00':
        $paid = 1;
        $recurring = 30;
        break;
    case '10.00':
        $paid = 2;
        $recurring = 30;
        break;
    case '100.00':
        $paid = 2;
        $recurring  = 365;
        break;
endswitch;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `as_users` SET paid=?, reg_date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, end_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL ? DAY) WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('dis', $paid, $recurring, $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: smart method, but 2 are monthly and the 100$ version is yearly

Comment: I recieved 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in(the line that starts the prepare statement)

Comment: @user3158844 Then your `mysqli` connection string failed.

Comment: oh wow accidently wrote my mysqli password incorrectly hold on fixing

Comment: wow it still only fired first one and I payed for the 10$ version hmm

Comment: @user3158844 Then `exit($amount)` at the top what does it come out to?

Comment: Oh I fixed it! Turns out my php was firing the first $stmt because I didn't update my other line of code of my IPN.php page, thanks so much for your help and amazing clean, safe code repped :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use

`number_format($amount, 2, '.', '')` instead of number_format($amount, 2) for returning  english notation without thousands separator.

i.e

> english notation without thousands separator

```
$number = 1234.56;
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

> 1234.56

and to compare two float values use BC math function

```
$b = 10.00;
$a = number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');
    bccomp($a, $b)==0  // returns true if both values are 10.00
```